# Diacritics in chat names are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, display-names, chat

My name is displayed as

> `&#211;lafu`

in the chat.

So it is not displaying html encoded characters well. Oh and why strip off the R in my name? Possibly name length or something

Comment: They just hate you!

Comment: Isn't that an acute?

Comment: @Grace - re-titled to Diacritics; that covers all?most? bases...

Comment: @Grace it's whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "r" is just overflow - can you try making the window bigger to see if you get more? The Ó is simply a bug. We'll fix that ;p

Comment: Ya it's an overflow, I'm running on 1280x1024 though, if I extend it onto the LCD TV then I can see the R

Comment: @Ólafur - I don't imagine the &#211; is helping re space...